# Setting a List to another List in C#

Tags: c#

```
public static string[] traitNames = { "Happiness", "Respect", "Authority" };
private ArrayList arraysNames = new ArrayList() { traitNames, suppliesNames };
string[] currentArrayNames = new string[] { arraysNames[i1] };//error message here
```

Error message: *Cannot implicitly convert 'object' to 'string'.*  What can I do to make currentArrayNames = traitNames via. referencing it through arraysNames?  Thanks!  Note: I did not include suppliesNames, although it does exist, much similar to traitNames.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃ПepeúpaツRight on this line: private ArrayList arraysNames = new ArrayList() { traitNames, suppliesNames };

Comment: Your ArrayList is not types, so it does not know which object is stored in the ArrayList.

You might use List<YourType> instead.

Comment: Important  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.8#remarks .

Comment: Your probably looking for a 'Jagged List' or a nested one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the non-generic `ArrayList` type - so the compile-time type of `arraysNames[i1]` is `object`, not `string[]`. You should almost *never* use `ArrayList` in modern code - since 2005, the preferred generic equivalent has been `List<T>`. So this code will compile:

```cs
public static string[] traitNames = { "Happiness", "Respect", "Authority" };
private List<string[]> arraysNames = new List<string[]> { traitNames, suppliesNames };

// Later in code
string[] currentArrayNames = arraysNames[i1];
```

Note that this doesn't create a *new* array - it just uses the existing one. I'm assuming that's what you wanted, really.

If you *absolutely* can't change the type of `arraysNames`, you can just cast instead:

```cs
string[] currentArrayNames = (string[]) arraysNames[i1];
```

It's definitely better to use `List<string[]>` instead though.

As a side-note, I'd strongly recommend avoiding making fields public as you have with `traitNames`.

Comment: Thank you!  I tried this, however, and it gave me a new error message for the { traitNames, suppliesNames }; section of the code, saying, Argument 1 cannot be converted from 'string[]' to 'string'.  So I tried adding in brackets to both 'string's on this line, and then the same error moved to the third line instead.

Comment: @OnlineOne: I edited the answer to use a `List<string[]>` - did you spot that? It doesn't help that we don't have much context here - we don't know what `suppliesNames` is, or what you're trying to do. Hopefully the edited answer will work for you though.

Comment: I just spotted it!  And I updated my answer to clarify that supplyNames is practically the same as traitNames.  Also, thank you!  It worked great.

Answer (score 2):

ArrayList will always give you "object"' type and you may have to do a specific type conversion here .

```
 ArrayList arraysNames = new ArrayList() { traitNames, suppliesNames };
 string[] currentArrayNames = arraysNames[1] as string[];
```

Comment: It doesn't seems what author wants. He obviously confused of generic and non-generic types and suggesting this solution would be very bed for him...