# How could I count an array directed at another array in C#?

Tags: c#

```
public static string[] traitNames = { "Happiness", "Respect", "Authority" };
public static string[] suppliesNames = { "Food", "Iron", "Gold" };
private List<string[]> arraysNames = new List<string[]> { traitNames, suppliesNames };
string[] currentArrayNames = arraysNames[i1];
int namesCount = currentArrayNames.Count;//ERROR HERE
```

Hello!  For some reason, on the last line where I try to Count, I get an error message over Count:

> Cannot convert method group "Count" to non-delegate type 'int'.

How would I be able to Count currentArrayNames' amount of children without getting this counting error?  Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59100928/setting-a-list-to-another-list-in-c-sharp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting a List to another List in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59100928/setting-a-list-to-another-list-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Remove `using System.Linq` and the error will suddenly make more sense

Comment: Or use `Count()` - note `()` -  from *Linq* which is the *same* for all collections

Comment: Please, have a look at updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `currentArrayNames.Length`, there is no `Count` property in `Array` [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.length?view=netframework-4.8)

```cs
int namesCount = currentArrayNames.Length;
```

Another option is to use `Count()` extension method from `System.Linq` [namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.8), as you've tried to done, but this is a method, not a property

```cs
int namesCount = currentArrayNames.Count();
```